# ROS_WARN messages go to stdout instead of stderr?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the [velodyne](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne?distro=kinetic) package in Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic. I am trying to log all the errors to a file. However, the ROS_WARN messages seem to go to the normal stdout instead of the stderr in ROS. This is not what is expected according to the [ROS logging documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging). Does anyone know why this might be happening? And if I am missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289256/ros_warn-messages-go-to-stdout-instead-of-stderr?/) by [kk93](https://answers.ros.org/users/34752/kk93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possibly an oversight. A fix's been [merged into melodic-devel](https://github.com/ros/rosconsole/pull/29).

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2019-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0